# Pandas equivalent of SQL Group By while concatenating columns

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have table having following columns:
firstname, surname, tel

something like this :

```
firstname    surname    tel
alex         topol      1234
jim          jimix      2312
alex         topol      2344
```

now I want to find numberof tel per person and sort, so I write this in SQL:

```
select concat(firstname,' ',surname),count(*) from wp_eqra_requests group by concat(firstname,' ',surname) order by count(*) desc
```

But do I write this in Python Pandas? I tried using **groupby** but had no sucess in concatening two columns:

```
numUsers = df.groupby(by=["firstname", "surname")["tel"].count()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to SQL you can use the add operator to concat two columns then groupby and count the values

```
df.groupby(df['firstname'] + ' ' + df['surname'])['tel'].count()
```

---

```
alex topol    2
jim jimix     1
Name: tel, dtype: int64
```